# Drupal 8: Node "options" does not exist for Node "Drupal\Core\Template\TwigNodeTrans" error after update

Tags: theming, updating

after updating Drupal 8 from 8.6.14 to 8.6.15 (twig v1.40.1) I suddenly get this kind of fatal errors:

```
 Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\SyntaxError: "An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Node "options" does not exist for Node "Drupal\Core\Template\TwigNodeTrans".")
```

It happens in my custom theme, but also in `core/themes/classy/templates/views/views-mini-pager.html.twig`

Do you know how to solve this or what the origin is?

Comment: This is known issue, it happened to me once, I just downgrade to twig 1.37 there is thread of this issue on drupal, but it's not fixed yet.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3051269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3051269 this is now resolved by the drupal team. Whatever caused the error seems to be fixed now in drupal 8.7.0